# How to make "Show More" in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a blog. And I want to load at first 10 posts and later the button "Show More". On click on it appends +10 new posts to the .posts div.

How can I do it? I think, that I must to append every time

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %> 
   <%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```

where

```
@posts = Post.all.offset(changeable_variable_here).limit(10)
```

How can I realize it?

Comment: why jquery tag? if you want to get help in jquery then you need to post some rendered html and post the jquery code that you've tried so far....

Answer (score 2):

You need pagination.

Have a look at https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

An example with jQuery: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great gem to handle pagination: [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari)

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade Check out this page on the [kaminari wiki](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To:-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery) !